# Getting the name of the calling class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, metaprogramming, mixins

I'm trying to figure out how to get the name of the class that called a module function in a plugin-based application of mine.

`caller` seems to give me a file/line number, which is *workable*, but seems a bit hacky and not idiomatic.

Example code:

```
module AwesomeModule
  def self.get_caller
    puts #some unknown code here
  end
end


class AwesomeClass
  def initialize
    AwesomeModule::get_caller
  end
end

a = AwesomeClass.new # ideal return => "AwesomeClass"
```

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but typically `AwesomeClass` would `include` AwesomeModule rather than accessing it the way you are here. In that case you could make `get_caller` inside AwesomeModule a regular instance method and do `self.class`.

Comment: @spike This works too! Okay, so it's clear I was approaching this the wrong way. I'm just barely starting to get a handle on this type of metaprogramming stuff and it still makes my head hurt a bit :)

Comment: Cool, I added an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You typically use ruby modules by including them. Try this:

```
module AwesomeModule
  def get_caller
    self.class
  end
end

class AwesomeClass
  include AwesomeModule
  def initialize
    get_caller
  end
end

a = AwesomeClass.new #  "AwesomeClass"
```

Also, note that in your question `get_caller` is being called on the `AwesomeModule` module itself, further complicating the issue.